# Create Map from Two Lists

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a list in Neo4J, say `['a', 'b', 'c']`. I want to make a map `M` that will give me the index of each entry, for example so that `M['b']=1`.

I'd like to do this with the list as a variable in order to avoid explicitly writing out the map.

This should work as in the query:

```
WITH {a:0, b:1, c:2} AS M
return M["a"]
```

I've tried things like:

```
WITH ['a', 'b', 'c'] AS ps
UNWIND ps as X
RETURN {X:range(0,size(ps)-1)}
```

but get errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [apoc.map.fromLists](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#map-functions) function should be useful:

```
WITH ['a', 'b', 'c'] AS ps
RETURN apoc.map.fromLists(ps, RANGE(0, SIZE(ps)-1)) AS m
```

The result is:

```
╒═══════════════════╕
│"m"                │
╞═══════════════════╡
│{"a":0,"b":1,"c":2}│
└───────────────────┘
```